# How can I read with firebug a var (without console.logging)

Tags: javascript, console, firebug

I would like to know the value of a var by using firebug.
I know the way to get them with console.log or alert.
In my case I can't change the code to add something.
Is there a way to read a var without changing code by firebug?

I made a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JdEvU/2/

Is there a possibilitie to get/see the value of targetPosition in firebug?

```
function handleWheel(evt){
    var e = window.event || evt; // old IE support
    var delta = -e.wheelDelta || (40 * e.detail);
    console.log('I am awake');
    advance(delta);

}

    function advance(delta){
    direction = (Math.abs(delta) > 2) ? ((delta > 0) ? 1 : -1) : ((delta < 0) ? 1 : -1);
    var targetPosition = delta * 5;
    console.log('delta: ',delta);    
   }



// Events
function addEvent(evt, handler, element){
    if(window.addEventListener){
        if(evt == 'mousewheel'){
            // Firefox
            element.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", handler, false);
        }
        element.addEventListener(evt, handler, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent('on' + evt, handler);
}

addEvent('mousewheel', handleWheel, window);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a local variable, so I guess the only possibility is to use the debugger here.
To do so add a breakpoint on next line and add `targetPosition` to the watched variables. As soon as the line is executed the script execution will stop at it and you'll be able to see the value.

[image]

Comment: thx i had always ReferenceError: test is not defined, but with your hint it works.